# Clean Build Folder option disabled in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode5

I have an iOS project that builds and runs fine, but the "Clean Build Folder..." option is disabled.  As a matter of fact, it is disabled in all of my projects (all iOS, some in workspaces).

They have not been upgraded from previous Xcode version as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830444/xcode-4-menu-build-and-clean-options-disabled).

[image]

To See the `Clean Build Folder...` option, hold the option key while viewing the Product menu.

What can I do to enable it?

### Update:

Almost a year later. Currently on Xcode 6.3. Still no luck.

Comment: I am using 5.01 right now, seems it is new option in new version. right?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how new it is. Does it show up for you if you hold the option key? I probably should have mentioned that above.

Comment: yep, it shows, but what's the differences between? )

Comment: try to build and then i thin you will see this option as enabled

Comment: I believe 'Clean' simply deletes all compiled components, which is useful if Xcode has not noticed that something needs to be recompiled, and 'Clean Build Folder..' supposedly erases the projects build folder, though I've not actually used it :p I wish I could figure this out as it would be pretty useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried the following steps.
Preference --> Locations --> 
For derived data, click "Advanced".
Inside build location, choose "Unique". 
The "Clear Build Folder" button appears again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a project in Xcode 8, and found that in addition to the setting @ycwjjjj mentioned, I also needed to check `File → Workspace Settings… → Advanced…` and switch away from `Custom Settings` to `Unique` (or `Xcode Default`).